# Cygwin exits immediately after invoking

Tags: cygwin

I just installed the newest version of cygwin and the terminal program is working fine but if I invoke bash from the windows command line it immediately $exit no matter what command I use. If I use bash --login it immediately %logout. If I run cygwin from the terminal every works fine. I have no idea what would be causing this isuse...

Comment: Do you have a `$HOME/.bash_logout` file?

Comment: There is no .bash_logout in my home directory the only bash.bash_logout files are in ..\cygwin\etc and ..\cygwin\etc\defaults\etc